# Like operator or with any other operator that can used

Tags: oracle

I want the records to be shown like BTN GLOBAL not BT airways.There should be  no record like BT shops or BT cars or BT  airways.Please guide with the query.

Comment: `like 'BTN%' ` ?

Comment: Could be `upper(that_column)` as well, according to what you said so far. Could you explain - in plain English - what you really want?

Comment: @digvijay apart from N there can be any character... So this can't be use like this...

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'BTN global' from dual union all
  3     select 'BT airways' from dual union all
  4     select 'BT shops'   from dual union all
  5     select 'BTX Little' from dual
  6    )
  7  select * From test
  8  where not regexp_like(col, '^BT ');

COL
----------
BTN global
BTX Little

SQL>
```